# Need changes in the script for the game ambient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am a game developer using Unity2D. I'm doing a fairly simple task, but I've already lost my mind and want to turn to other living people so as not to go completely crazy!
So, we have an Ambient Manager, which should play one of the random tracks of the array at certain locations/scenes in the game. That is, roughly speaking, the game must somehow understand on which stages this or that combination of random tracks will be played. It would seem that I could simply place prefabs across all scenes, but I needed seamlessness in playing music, which is why I had to add conditions not to destroy the object.

in short, the problem is that now only one combination of tracks is playing, although I would like to make it so that one combination plays SEAMLESSLY on some stages, and the other on others. In addition, some scenes do not need ambient at all (for example, the main menu). Please help me!

**AmbientManager Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class AmbientManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip[] audioClips

    private AudioSource audioSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, audioClips.Length);
        AudioClip randomClip = audioClips[randomIndex];

        audioSource.clip = randomClip;

        audioSource.Play();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Pause_menu.GameIsPaused)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.UnPause();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: sounds like you need groups of things that get set as they enter areas, so it has like music list for an area, environmental sounds which play too, and so on..

Comment: This is hardly a solution

Comment: well you seem to want it to play something dependant on where it is - you dont have that, so i suggested it, you also want multiple things played, so splitting them out further also helps with that.. but hey, no it wasnt an answer it was a comment :P

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying to help me. I'm not sure I understand your last comment, but in that case, could you help me with this in the form of a code solution? I would be very grateful since I don't understand how to connect the logic and the script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a seamless transition effect, I suggest you add another AudioSource on your prefab and interact between the two clips, smoothly decreasing the volume in the first and increasing the volume in the second.

I also suggest using DoTween to avoid writing asynchronous methods or coroutines.

Here's an example:

```
public class AmbientManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource firstSource;
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource secondSource;

    private AudioClip[] audioClips;
    private AudioSource currentPlayingSource;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        //GET CLIPS FROM AUDIO GROUP
        //SetAudioClips(SET CLIPS)
        //PlayAmbient()
    }

    public void SetAudioClips(AudioClip[] clips)
    {
        audioClips = clips;
    }

    public void PlayAmbient()
    {
        AudioSource previousSource = currentPlayingSource;
        currentPlayingSource = previousSource == firstSource ? secondSource : firstSource;

        currentPlayingSource.volume = 0;
        currentPlayingSource.clip = GetRandomAmbient();
        currentPlayingSource.Play();
        
        //DOTween for smooth volume decrease
        DOTween.To(() => currentPlayingSource.volume, x => currentPlayingSource.volume = x, 1, 1);
        
        //DOTween for smooth volume increase
        if(previousSource != null)
            DOTween.To(() => previousSource.volume, x => previousSource.volume = x, 0, 1).OnComplete(() => previousSource.Stop());
    }

    private AudioClip GetRandomAmbient()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, audioClips.Length);
        return audioClips[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

In the example above, the PlayAmbient and SetAudioClips methods are public, so just call them to set new tracks and start playing them whenever you need.